# The Mockk library does not redefine the class in runTime

Tags: kotlin, ktor, mockk

There is an application that connects to RabbitMQ at startup, all I'm trying to do is implement a test and at the same time not access RabbitMQ from the test. For some reason, my changes in the test are not applied at RunTime

```kotlin
    package some_app.processor


import io.ktor.server.application.Application
import io.ktor.server.application.call
import io.ktor.server.response.respond
import io.ktor.server.response.respondText
import io.ktor.server.routing.get
import io.ktor.server.routing.routing
import ru.noisedetector.processor.clients.RabbitService
import ru.noisedetector.processor.props.CustomApplicationProperties


fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused") // Referenced in application.conf
fun Application.module() {
    val appProps = CustomApplicationProperties(environment.config)
    val host = appProps.getString("rabbitProps.host")
    val port = appProps.getInt("rabbitProps.port")
    val username = appProps.getString("rabbitProps.username")
    val password = appProps.getString("rabbitProps.password")
    val queueName = appProps.getString("rabbitProps.queue")
    val rabbitService = RabbitService(
        host = host,
        port = port,
        username = username,
        password = password,
        queueName = queueName,
    )
    rabbitService.defaultExchangeAndQueue()
    rabbitService.consumeQueue()



    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello, world!")
        }

        get("/json/jackson") {
            call.respond(mapOf("hello" to "world"))
        }
    }
}
```

Below test:

```kotlin
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.client.statement.bodyAsText
import io.ktor.server.config.ApplicationConfig
import io.ktor.server.testing.testApplication
import io.mockk.MockKAnnotations
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.verify
import org.junit.Before
import ru.noisedetector.processor.clients.RabbitService
import ru.noisedetector.processor.module
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertEquals

class ApplicationTest {

    @Before
    fun setUp() = MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxUnitFun = true) // turn relaxUnitFun on for all mocks


    @Test
    fun testDevEnvironment() = testApplication {
        application {
            module()
        }
        environment {
            config = ApplicationConfig("application.conf")
        }

        val rabbitService: RabbitService = mockk()
        every { rabbitService.consumeQueue() } answers { nothing }
        every { rabbitService.defaultExchangeAndQueue() } answers { nothing }
        every { rabbitService.giveMeFactory() } returns mockk<ConnectionFactory>()
        val resp = client.get("/")
        assertEquals("Hello, world!", resp.bodyAsText())
        verify { rabbitService.defaultExchangeAndQueue() }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Kotlin so this might be a stupid question on my part, but I checked the documentation and didn't find any help there.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.13.5")
}
```

Here my error:

```
В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:59)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:63)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:160)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1131)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1294)
    at ru.noisedetector.processor.clients.RabbitService.defaultExchangeAndQueue(RabbitService.kt:42)
    at ru.noisedetector.processor.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:188)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:111)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:355)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:337)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:276)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine.start(TestApplicationEngine.kt:144)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine$DefaultImpls.start$default(ApplicationEngine.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.client.TestHttpClientEngine.execute(TestHttpClientEngine.kt:47)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.client.DelegatingTestClientEngine.execute(DelegatingTestClientEngine.kt:56)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$2.invokeSuspend(HttpClientEngine.kt:99)
    at _COROUTINE._BOUNDARY._(CoroutineDebugging.kt:46)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$DefaultImpls.executeWithinCallContext(HttpClientEngine.kt:100)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpClientEngine.kt:70)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpSend$DefaultSender.execute(HttpSend.kt:138)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRedirect$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRedirect.kt:64)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$3.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:151)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpSend$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpSend.kt:104)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:130)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt:38)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.execute$ktor_client_core(HttpClient.kt:191)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.executeUnsafe(HttpStatement.kt:108)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.execute(HttpStatement.kt:47)
    at ApplicationTest$testDevEnvironment$1.invokeSuspend(ApplicationTest.kt:96)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationKt$testApplication$builder$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestApplication.kt:335)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:59)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:63)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:160)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1173)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1131)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1294)
    at ru.noisedetector.processor.clients.RabbitService.defaultExchangeAndQueue(RabbitService.kt:42)
    at ru.noisedetector.processor.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:188)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:111)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:355)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:337)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:276)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.TestApplicationEngine.start(TestApplicationEngine.kt:144)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngine$DefaultImpls.start$default(ApplicationEngine.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.client.TestHttpClientEngine.execute(TestHttpClientEngine.kt:47)
    at io.ktor.server.testing.client.DelegatingTestClientEngine.execute(DelegatingTestClientEngine.kt:56)
    at io.ktor.client.engine.HttpClientEngine$executeWithinCallContext$2.invokeSuspend(HttpClientEngine.kt:99)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:100)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
```

By mistake, it is seen that the RabbitService is trying to access the service

Comment: The problem is that in your module you're creating a `RabbitService` instance directly, so there's no way for you to replace it with a mock object in your test. You need to use something like dependency injection so that you can inject the real service to your "real" module, while in your test you can inject the mock one

Comment: @user2340612 is right, you can try setting up Koin DI with your ktor application, that is the most popular one at the moment